# failed importing ICUFoldingFilter while using pylucene

Tags: pylucene, pyicu

When issuing an import statement

```
from lucene.ICUFoldingFilter import ICUFoldingFilter
```

I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError: (2, 'No such file or directory', '~/miniconda3/envs/lucene/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lucene-9.4.1-py3.11-linux-x86_64.egg/lucene/resources/org/apache/lucene/analysis/icu/utr30.dat')
```

I have python3-icu 2.8.1 and libicu70 package installed in my ubuntu and icu 58.2 and pyicu2.7.4 installed in my conda virtual environment. Running Ubuntu 22.

I can import and run ICUNormalizer2Filter just fine after installing the ICU packages, but not the
ICUFoldingFilter. I have Java OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.6+10 . What am I missing?